# Java Hibernate java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown parameter position: 1

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, hql

This is my query method :

```
@Query(value = "select new com.twognation.hub.dto.GameDTO(game.id, game.name, game.active, game.description, game.coverImage, game.logo, game.backgroundImage, game.featuredImage, game.characterImage, game.smallCoverImage, count(tournament.id) as tournamentCount) from Game game left join Tournament tournament on game.id=tournament.game where lower(game.name) like '%:name%' group by game.id order by tournamentCount desc, game.id",
                countQuery = "select count(1) from Game game left join Tournament tournament on game.id=tournament.game where lower(game.name) like '%:name%' group by game.id order by tournamentCount desc, game.id")
Page<GameDTO> findAllOrderByTournamentCount(@Param("name") String name, Pageable page);
```

When I call this method i get this error :

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown parameter position: 1    
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.QueryParameterBindingsImpl.getBinding(QueryParameterBindingsImpl.java:240)  
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.setParameter(AbstractProducedQuery.java:503)  
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.setParameter(AbstractProducedQuery.java:104)  
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.ParameterBinder.bind(ParameterBinder.java:141)     
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.StringQueryParameterBinder.bind(StringQueryParameterBinder.java:61)    
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.ParameterBinder.bind(ParameterBinder.java:101)     
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SpelExpressionStringQueryParameterBinder.bind(SpelExpressionStringQueryParameterBinder.java:76)    
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.ParameterBinder.bindAndPrepare(ParameterBinder.java:161)   
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.ParameterBinder.bindAndPrepare(ParameterBinder.java:152)   
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractStringBasedJpaQuery.doCreateQuery(AbstractStringBasedJpaQuery.java:81)     
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.createQuery(AbstractJpaQuery.java:190)    
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$PagedExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:186)     
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:87)   
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:116)  
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:106)    
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:492)     
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:475)   
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)    
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:56)    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)    
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)   at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282)  
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)    
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)   
    ... 172 common frames omitted
```

Comment: try to use JpaRepository or CrudRepository, in this case you will not need to use @Query and maybe you'll fix the problem

Comment: `'%:name%'` is a String literal ... do you see why that may be a problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This :

```
'%:name%'
```

In JPA is just a native String, to solve this issue you can use `CONCAT` operator like so :

```
CONCAT('%', :name, '%')
```

This will be converted later to `'%some_value%'` for example

Comment: That worked. One more question. In game i have Set of genres. How can i add to query to filter by specific genre id ?

Comment: @user3364181 maybe you can use `IN` for example `:genre IN g.genres`

Comment: i got this error when i tried that :
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Syntax error in SQL statement

Comment: @user3364181 It is bad to ask other questions beside the original question, so instead please create a new question where you describe every thing about what you want to do exactly and what you tried so far and I'm sure that we can help you :) like that I can't understand what you do or what you want exactly I'm waiting your new question ok

Answer (score 2):

Look like you have problem with `like`.

Instead of

```
'%:name%'
```

do:

```
%:name%
```

Comment: This fails for SQL Server 2016. The CONCAT suggestion up above works.